# Developing a TV application

Tags: keyboard, hbbtv

I have been trying to build a TV application, using an SD. 
I have got features like image gallery, video player running,
However, I also wanted to add a virtual on-screen keyboard that works with up-down left-right arrow keys. Can somebody help me with how to get started?

Answer (score 0):

When I wanted to do this with my Vestel (Polaroid Branded) smart TV, which uses "Opera for TV devices" as it's HbbTV browser, I found that I didn't need to.

I simply just used HTML text fields and input types where needed, and as soon as I clicked into them, the browser/OS kernel popped up an onscreen keyboard that was built in for me.

However, I did do some research to see if I needed it, and on some devices you do, whilst I never actually implemented it (My app was just for my own use) the "BBC Television Application Layer" (TAL for short) : https://github.com/bbc/tal had pretty good keyboard support.

Another one that might be worth looking at is "Mautilus SDK" : https://github.com/mautilus/sdk

Be aware though, both are horribly convoluted and use quite complex code where it's really not needed.